# User Mentions Twitter

Tags: api, twitter

I was doing a bit of research on the Twitter API and while I could find something for internal user mentions, I couldn't find an API call that grabs the authenticating user's mentions from other users. Is there a way to grab this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean [GET statuses/mentions_timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-mentions_timeline)?

That will show you all the mentions of the authenticated user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, that's the one that grabs only the authorized users Mentions. I'm looking for something that grabs all mentions of the user by other users.

Comment: Am I mistaken on this? Does it return mentions of the user, or mentions by the user?

Comment: I dug a bit further into the documentation of the function, and I believe I was originally mistaken. I misread something when I first found this function. This is what I'm looking for. I'll accept the answer when I verify this. Thanks again.